# Lexer and unicode, e.g. German mutated vowel

Tags: unicode, char, antlr, lexer, antlrworks

Two questions:
1. Why is the string `abäcd` not recognized (ANTLRWorks 1.4.2) with the grammar below (the result is only `abcd`, that means the German mutated vowel `ä` is missing)?
2. How can I divide `Vowels` in `VowelsUpper` and `VowelsLower` and use both rules in rule `Vowels`?

```
grammar Vowels1a;

CharLower
  : 'a'..'z'
  ;

Vowels
  : 'ä' | 'ö' | 'ü' | 'Ä'| 'Ö' | 'Ü'
  ;

test
  : ( CharLower | Vowels )+
  ;
```

Answer (score 2):

> **ANTLRStarter wrote:**
>
> 1 . Why is the string abäcd not recognized (ANTLRWorks 1.4.2) with the grammar below (the result is only abcd, that means the German mutated vowel ä is missing?

I could not reproduce this. Both ANTLRWorks' interpreter and debugger (1.4.2) produce the following parse tree:

[image]

And a small manual test also shows this:

### Main.java

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Vowels1aLexer lexer = new Vowels1aLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("abäcd"));
    Vowels1aParser parser = new Vowels1aParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.test();
  }
}
```

### Vowels1a.g

```java
grammar Vowels1a;

test
 : ( CharLower {System.out.println("CharLower :: " + $CharLower.text);}
   | Vowels    {System.out.println("Vowels    :: " + $Vowels.text);}
   )+
 ;

CharLower
 : 'a'..'z'
 ;

Vowels
 : 'ä' | 'ö' | 'ü' | 'Ä'| 'Ö' | 'Ü'
 ;
```

And to run the demo:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool Vowels1a.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main
```

which will print:

```
CharLower :: a
CharLower :: b
Vowels    :: ä
CharLower :: c
CharLower :: d
```

> **ANTLRStarter wrote:**
>
> 2 . How can I divide Vowels in VowelsUpper and VowelsLower and use both rules in rule Vowels?

Create two `fragment` rules (`VowelsUpper` and `VowelsLower`) and let `Vowels` match both these `fragment`s:

```java
Vowels
 : VowelsUpper
 | VowelsLower
 ;

fragment VowelsUpper
 : 'Ä'| 'Ö' | 'Ü'
 ;

fragment VowelsLower
 : 'ä' | 'ö' | 'ü'
 ;
```

Be aware that you cannot use `fragment` rules in your parser rules, only from other lexer rules!

Comment: Bart, thanks again - strange really. Tried it again with ANTLRWorks' debugger - same problem. Tomorrow I will try it with the interpreter.

Comment: I've seen ANTLRWorks add some junk bytes at the end of grammars causing it to respond strangely. Try opening the grammar in a normal text editor and see if there are some odd bytes at the end (and remove them). If it's still the same, try my command line demo with the `Main` class: that _must_ work.

Comment: @ANTLRStarter, I also expanded my answer a bit, I missed your 2nd question.

Comment: Yep, thanks to one of your other answers I'm aware of that problem. Therefore I check strange grammars in hex mode. Debugger output complains about `Test_input.txt line 1:2 no viable alternative at character '?'` after `CharLower :: a`. Checked `Test_input.txt` in hex mode, too: `abäcd` in hex `61 62 E4 63 64`.

Comment: Demo works, too. Just tried it with ANTLRWorks 1.4.3, same problem.

Comment: Concerning my second question, I have complemented that question.

Comment: @ANTLRStarter, I presume that the second part of your question, regarding VowelsUpper and VowelsLower, you simply did as I suggested, no? And about ANTLRWorks: I have no idea why you're getting different results than I get.

Comment: Yep Bart, I want then use rules `VowelsUpper` and `VowelsLower` in rule `Vowels`, but how - with `fragment`?

Comment: @ANTLRStarter, ah, I see you added the part _"... and use both rules in rule Vowels"_ after I answered. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1:
That smells very much like an encoding problem. "61 62 E4 63 64" means that the file is encoded using iso-8859-1 (or that windows-something variant). ANTLRWorks seems to use utf-8 and I see no obvious way to change that.

I assume you ran the debugger with that file as input. When saving the file as utf-8, it works fine for me and with iso-8859-1 the 'ä' is missing. I cannot reproduce the NoViableAlt error in ANTLRWorks 1.4.3, the 'ä' seems to be just missing from the input stream - perhaps java's utf8 decoder silently skips invalid sequences...

If you build your own app, you can specify yourself which encoding the input stream/file uses. In Python the ANTLRFileStream/ANTLRInputStream have a handy 'encoding' argument for that reason.

Comment: Ben, many thanks for your efforts - I'm just using the Input Text/Text field and `abäcd` in the debugger. Checked it again now with ANTLRWorks 1.4.2 and 1.4.3. Problem as mentioned (but no error message now). When using my file the Java-demo from Bart works (coded `61 62 E4 63 64`).